# NameError: name 'nan' is not defined while using eval

Tags: python

I'm running a grid search for xgboost.  I'm iterating through all the possible parameter combinations.
I have an expression as follows.

```
best_params="{'__init__': {'objective': 'reg:squarederror', 'max_depth': 5, 'learning_rate': 0.1, 'n_estimators': 5, 'verbosity': None, 'booster': 'gbtree', 'tree_method': 'exact', 'n_jobs': None, 'gamma': None, 'min_child_weight': None, 'max_delta_step': None, 'subsample': 0.8, 'colsample_bytree': 0.85, 'colsample_bylevel': None, 'colsample_bynode': None, 'reg_alpha': None, 'reg_lambda': None, 'scale_pos_weight': None, 'base_score': None, 'random_state': 123, 'missing': nan, 'num_parallel_tree': None, 'monotone_constraints': None, 'interaction_constraints': None, 'importance_type': 'gain', 'gpu_id': None, 'validate_parameters': None, 'predictor': None, 'enable_categorical': False, 'kwargs': None}}"

final_params=eval(best_params)
```

I'm getting the following error while running this.

```
NameError: name 'nan' is not defined
```

one of the parameters 'missing' has nan as the value in the dictionary. What should I do to avoid this error?

Comment: You wrote " 'missing': nan " and you didn't defined it.
You should write None maybe

Comment: Removing tag `xgboost` as this question has nothing to do with data science.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```py
from numpy import nan
# or
nan = float('nan')
```